# to get value using key in the map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

**mapper input:**

```
hi how are you 
how is your  job 
how is your family
what is hadoop hi
```

**reducer input:**

```
hadoop[1]
hi[1,1]
how[1,1,1]
is[1,1,1]
your[1,1]
```

mapper logic to store and retrive data:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hm=new HashMap<String,Integer>();  
 hm.put("hadoop",[1]);  
 hm.put("hi",[2]);  
 hm.put("is",[3]);  

 String val=(String)newmap.get("is");//  
output.collect(new Text(text),new Text(n))

 }
```

My problem is, that I want to print **"is"** value (that is 3) but I don't want my code to perform a comparison for every input string. My code should search only once at the end (after inserting all the key value pairs).

**example:**

If I have 1000 key value pairs then it should insert all the key value pairs first then  search should start that is( `String val=(String)newmap.get("is")`).

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the same key for all the values in the reducer's input. for e.g

```
(1,hadoop)
(1,hi1)
(1,hadoop)....
```

Then we add the count of the distinct string tokens in the reducer method inside the iterable itself:-

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hm=new HashMap<String,Integer>();  

Public void reduce(Intwritable key, Iterable(Text) values, Context context){
int i=1
String token= values.toString();
if(hm.get(token)== null){
hm.put(token,i);
}else{
i=hm.get(token)+1;
hm.put(token,i);
}
}
```

After the iterable loop we can output the result.

```
String val=(String)hm.get("is");//  
context.write(NUllwritable.get(),new Text(val);
```